# What is most important in building a regression model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

When I build a regression model, which is considered most important:

1. removing insignificant variables,
2. checking jfor multicollinearity and removing those variables that contribute to it,
3. multiple R-Squared,
4. or something else?

If I have to take care of all of the above, what should be my order of preference?

If I want to evaluate the model, is there is hard and fast rule that says residuals should be normally distributed?

Comment: What are your larger goals?  What do you want from the model, once you've built it?

Comment: I am trying to predict a variable with my model. I did the back tracking and the results almost similar without one particular variable. By using min-max accuracy min_max_accuracy <- mean(apply(Backtrack, 1, min) / apply(Backtrack, 1, max)), I am getting values of 73.5 and if i take one extra variable, i am getting the value as 75. Which one should i consider ?. should i go with model with less variable ?

Comment: OK.  You can find a great deal of material about all this on our site.  [Here is a very focused search to consider](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+regression+diagno*+-logistic+-poisson+score%3A2).